# Java BMI program

Tags: java

The first part of the code is working, the program takes inputs as height and weight as displays an output message. When I press n I can go to the second part and take inputs for height in inches and the weight in pounds. As soon as I take them the program outputs the resulting bmi is: Nan. and the variable bmi might not have been initialized. i want to convert the height and weight from inches and pounds to meters and then show the resulting bmi This is my code:

```
package uly14th;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BmiCalculator {

    private static float BMI2;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char Y; 
        char y; 
        char Q;
        char n;
        char N;
        float heightInMeters, weightInKilograms, BMI;
        float heightInInches, weightInpounds;
        float heightInMeters2 = 0, weightInKilograms2 = 0;
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please state whether you are going to use kilograms & meters or, inches & pounds");
        System.out.println("If you want to use the former please press Y or if you want to use the latter please press N");
        Q = input.next().charAt(0);
        if(Q == 'y' || Q == 'Y' ) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the height in meters: ");
            heightInMeters = input.nextFloat();
            System.out.println(" and weight in kilograms: "); 
            weightInKilograms = input.nextFloat();
            
            BMI =  weightInKilograms / (heightInMeters * heightInMeters);
           
            System.out.println("The resulting BMI of the person is: " +BMI);
            if (BMI < 18.5){
                System.out.println("The personis underweight");
            }
            else if ((BMI<=25.0) && (BMI >= 18.5)){
                System.out.println("The person is normal");
            }
            else if ((BMI >= 25.0) && (BMI <=30.0 )){
                System.out.println("The personis obese");
            }
            else if(BMI>=30.0) {
                System.out.println("The person is obese and should exercise");
            }
        }
        if ((Q == 'n') || (Q == 'N')){
            System.out.println("Please enter the height in inches: ");
            
            heightInInches = input.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("Please enter the weight in pounds: ");
            weightInpounds = input.nextFloat();
            
            heightInInches = 0.0254f * heightInMeters2;
            weightInpounds = 0.453592f * weightInKilograms2;
          
            BMI =  weightInKilograms / (heightInMeters * heightInMeters);
            
            System.out.println("The resulting BMI of the person is: " +BMI); 
            
            if (BMI < 18.5){
                System.out.println("The personis underweight");
            }
            else if ((BMI<=25.0) && (BMI >= 18.5)){
                System.out.println("The person is normal");
            }
            else if ((BMI >= 25.0) && (BMI <=30.0 )){
                System.out.println("The personis obese");
            }
            else if(BMI>=30.0) {
                System.out.println("The person is obese and should exercise");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Please make sure you run the program again and then only use the characters n,N,y,Y. ");
        }   
    }        
}
```

This is the error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - variable BMI might not have been initialized
at uly14th.BmiCalculator.main(BmiCalculator.java:82)

Comment: At the branch where you press `N`, you still use the variables for `weightInKilograms` and `heightInMeters`, dispite not initializing / reading them there. For this branch you should be using the read values of `heightInInches` and `weightInPounds`. But there I can see that you are multiplying a fixed value by `heightInMeters2`, which is 0... So you might just want to check through your variables and remove the unnecessary ones and make sure to initialize all variables before using them.

Comment: "heightInInches = input.nextFloat();" => should be correct. "heightInInches = 0.0254f * heightInMeters2;" ... overwrites the just gathered input with uninitialized data (heightInMeters2)
"BMI =  weightInKilograms / (heightInMeters * heightInMeters);" those are definitely not set based on input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the row (line 82)

```
 BMI =  weightInKilograms / (heightInMeters * heightInMeters);
```

you use the variables `weightInKilograms`  and `heightInMeters` which has never been initialized, hence your error.

I suspect you want to do the conversion to meters and kilograms from inches and pounds before calculating the BMI. You can do this by simply putting the following lines before the BMI calculation

```
heightInMeters = 0.0254f * heightInInches;
weightInKilograms = 0.453592f * weightInPounds;

BMI =  weightInKilograms / (heightInMeters * heightInMeters); //Now you can calculate the BMI using your variables since they have been assigned a value and is therefore initialized
```

Answer (score 1):

```
heightInMeters = 0.0254f * heightInInches ;
weightInKilograms = 0.453592f * weightInpounds ;
      
BMI =  weightInKilograms / (heightInMeters * heightInMeters);
```

should do the trick (... in case the constants are correct)